# I want to create website from this method "example.php?id=33" to this "example/properties/property-name"

Tags: php, html, content-management-system

i want to create a dynamic webpage. Usually done by passing id
url: exmple.php?id=555 etc. but i want know how this url method 
url: example/properties/property-name done?

Comment: Have you searched for the answer prior to posting here?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.